# Cleartool.exe multiple commands

Tags: shell, clearcase, cleartool

I want to execute multiple commands in the cleartool.exe console, but `;` or `&&` doesnt work.

Example:

```
cd /myView; ct mkact myActivity
```

Any suggestions to run this?

I need to use cleartool.exe

Comment: Don't chain your commands in a cleartool session: do it in a cmd like I mention below.

Comment: So... it is not possible.... 
Im using cleartool.exe because Im calling this into vb.net code... my application runs several cleartool commands thats why I try that...

Comment: vb.net can exec a cmd, in which you can chain your commands.

Comment: yes but the users that will use the app may not everybody have permissions to execute cmd

Answer (score 0):

If you are running windows, you can include cleartool commands in a command like:

`cd /d m:\tempview\testvob1 & cleartool desc .`

Note the /d option. Otherwise the DRIVE won't change and you won't see the directory. You can also use pushd/popd to change the directory.

Multiple cleartool commands can be chained together the same way.

On unix, the semicolon works like the & sign.

If you want to put a bunch of cleartool commands together, you can do something like this:

1. Create a text file with commands to run
2. run cleartool < text file

   `m:\tempview\mkvobtest-try2>copy con cleartool_stuff.txt
   find -all -type l -print
   desc .
   desc .@@
   quit
   ^Z
       1 file(s) copied.`

   `m:\tempview\mkvobtest-try2>cleartool < cleartool_stuff.txt
   M:\tempview\mkvobtest-try2\desktop
   M:\tempview\mkvobtest-try2\maketest2\make2.mk
   directory version ".@@\main\23"
   created 2014-04-11T12:10:40-04:00 by A User (auser.user@PC1)
   "Added directory element "Test"."
   Element Protection:
   User : NT:S-1-5-21-984945237-1216120022-2217536578-1001 : rwx
   Group: BUILTIN\Users : rwx
   Other:          : rwx
   element type: directory
   predecessor version: \main\22
   directory element ".@@"
   created 2010-03-10T12:25:01-05:00 by A User (auser.user@PC2)
   "Predefined directory element for root of versioned object base."
   element type: directory
   master replica: mrpeabody-rep@\mkvobtest-try2
   Protection:
   User : NT:S-1-5-21-984945237-1216120022-2217536578-1001 : rwx
   Group: BUILTIN\Users : rwx
   Other:          : rwx
   source pool: sdft  cleartext pool: cdft  derived pool: ddft`

   `m:\tempview\mkvobtest-try2>`

The same technique works on unix, but the shells often give you additional options to do this.

Comment: Hello Brian! I try your advice but it doesnt work...Here is the output that i get... Im Using the cleartool.exe from windows...

cleartool> cd /d M:\dyn_PJ_COREDOC_link & startview dyn_PJ_COREDOC_int
cleartool: Error: Extra arguments: "M:\dyn_PJ_COREDOC_link"
Usage: cd [dir-pname]

Comment: You're in the interactive cleartool shell. So the /d option doesn't exist, and command chaining isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple CMD session, you can chain command with:

```
cmd /v /c "cd C:\path\to\myview&& cleartool mkact anActivity"
```

That is more convenient than trying to do it in a `cleartool.exe` session.